# How can I properly debug a React Native application?

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I would like to set stops and check the variables and objects values during execution. Is that possible?

Comment: IntelliJ for example offers that capability ootb.

Comment: "I would like to set stops and check the variables and objects values during execution", I think the word you are looking for is debugger.

Comment: you can just use debugger inside your application. Then you need to debug the app (shake the phone / or hardware -> shake phone -- for iOS) and Remote JS remotely. After that, you need to click right on the chrome page and it will open the console. With this you will have access to ChromeDevTools where you can check everything you said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I learned how to debug the application with Visual Studio Code and it suits my needs. Thanks for all the answers.